# Trouble with Ruby on Rails and FileUpload

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, image-uploading

I've been struggling with this strange problem with uploading big images to the server. I am using [blueimp file image](http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/) upload on client and the server is Rails 4 with carrierwave for processing images (thought it seems it doesn't get to it anyway).

As long as the image is under something like 1.2 MB, everything is ok. But as soon as the image is bigger then this, I am getting this response from server instead of a normal one:

```
HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf8
X-Pow-Template: error_starting_application
Connection: keep-alive
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
```

The server, according to development.log, is performing a simple "Completed 201 Created in 1402ms", as is defined in routes.rb (no action is performed, though). The header sent to the server is:

```
POST /images HTTP/1.1
Host: mysite.dev
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 1081439
Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Origin: http://mysite.dev
X-CSRF-Token: ynCLWDzF90l3BhmMcmxF+KCFiws3tnQiFAuWp+Buqcw=
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/29.0.1547.65 Safari/537.36
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryT5ZwwFlboJY4Cz7n
Referer: http://mysite.dev/images/new
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8,ru;q=0.6
```

I don't really understand what I am doing wrong, since my client settings don't really differ much from the ones specified in Blueimp's demo:

```
  url: "/images"
  paramName: "image[image]"
  type: "POST"
  dataType: "json"
  formData: ""
  disableImageResize: false
  acceptFileTypes: /(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)$/i
```

The code for controller action is

```
def create
  @image = Image.create image_params
  respond_with @image, layout: false
end
```

And in case of smaller files everything goes smoothly:

```
HTTP/1.1 201 Created
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-UA-Compatible: chrome=1
Location: http://mysite.dev/images/298
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
ETag: "410e24f50d02125716bfc46eb7850c1f"
Cache-Control: max-age=0, private, must-revalidate
X-Request-Id: 40e527d0-e16a-4a4e-a2e5-6124d8e639ff
X-Runtime: 1.533655
Connection: close
```

The header sent from the client is the same, so no difference here. I guess there could be some problems with my server configuration (not accepting big files), but I cannot find it.

Thank you for your help!

UPD: Found the reason, it was actually pow that caused all the trouble. Everything works perfectly with native server running.

Comment: Could it be a timeout issue on the server side?

Comment: How can I check this? Is there some way to configure it?

Comment: But I think no, an error happens almost immediately, like in 2-3 seconds (in case of lesser sized file an upload can take 10 seconds or more).

Comment: If the server returns '201 Created', how come the client receives '500 internal server error'?

Comment: Ok, I've checked it again, and there is no 201 created message on server. 500 internal server error still there though.

Comment: Any stack trace associated with the internal server error?

Comment: How do i get it in Rails? What debugger should I use, I can't find a proper tutorial.

Comment: By default, in development mode, you should see `debug` level logging in your `log/development.log` file. Where did you see the '500 internal server error' on the server side? I assumed you found it in the log file. In that case, it should be just before or after that line in the log file.

Comment: Or, if by stack trace you mean log, then I got it. :)

Comment: No, there is no info about the error on the side, server just sends 500 internal server error silently.